# Cannot convert IActionResult to bool

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am writing a unit test on the web api method that returns a bool value.

Currently isUnique contains statuscode 200 and value true when executing the following line

```
var isUnique = controller.UniqueEmail(clientCompanyId, email);
```

How do I Assert it because I am getting error cannot convert IActionResult to bool error when i do

```
 Assert.False(isUnique);
```

Test

```
[Fact]
        public void Is_Not_UniqueEmail()
        {

            int clientCompanyId = 30;
            string email = "test.co.uk";

            var mockIdentityService = new Mock<IIdentityService>();

            mockIdentityService.Setup(x => x.CheckUniqueEmail(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
               .Returns(true);

            var controller = new SecurityController(mockIdentityService.Object, null, null, null, null);

            var isUnique = controller.UniqueEmail(clientCompanyId, email);

            Assert.False(isUnique);
        }
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("unique-email/{clientCompanyId:int}/{email}")]
    public IActionResult UniqueEmail(int clientCompanyId, string email)
    {
        var isUnique = _identityService.CheckUniqueEmail(clientCompanyId, email);
        if (isUnique)
        {
            return Ok(isUnique);
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound(isUnique);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller should probably just be:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("unique-email/{clientCompanyId:int}/{email}")]
public IActionResult UniqueEmail(int clientCompanyId, string email)
{
    if (!CompanyExists(clientCompanyId))
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    bool isUnique = _identityService.CheckUniqueEmail(clientCompanyId, email);
    return Ok(isUnique);
}
```

(`CompanyExists` returns true if a company is known else false)

and then

```
IActionResult response = controller.UniqueEmail(clientCompanyId, email);
OkObjectResult OKResponse = response as OkObjectResult;

Assert.IsNotNull(OKResponse);
Assert.AreEqual(false, OKResponse.Value);
```